# What is caret symbol ^ used for in css when selecting elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I encountered a css selector in a file like this:

```
#contactDetails ul li a, a[href^=tel] {....}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The circumflex character “^” as such has no defined meaning in CSS. The two-character operator “^=” can be used in [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings). Generally, `[attr^=val]` refers to those elements that have the attribute `attr` with a value that starts with `val`.

Thus, `a[href^=tel]` refers to such `a` elements that have the attribute `href` with a value that starts with `tel`. It is probably meant to distinguish telephone number links from other links; it’s not quite adequate for that, since the selector also matches e.g. `<a href="tel.html">...</a>` but it is probably meant to match only links with `tel:` as the protocol part. So `a[href^="tel:"]` would be safer.

Comment: this kinda oot, but what is the difference between `a[href^=tel]` and `a[href|=tel]` ? is there any diffence between `^` and `|`

Answer (score 9):

```css
a[href^="tel"]
```

(`^`) means it selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning/starting exactly with a given string.

Here it selects all the 'anchor' elements the value of `href` attribute starting exactly with a string `'tel'`

Comment: @Yannis Dran have you got it?

Comment: yes thank you all very much, I had got confused because into the html there was no value containing the string "tel".

Answer (score 5):

It means a tags whose href attribute begins with "tel"

Example:

```
<a href="tel123xxx">This is a link</a>
```

will match.

Answer (score 5):

The carat "^" used like that will match a tags where the href starts with "tel" ( http://csscreator.com/content/attribute-selector-starts )