# If already using the contains selector, why use the starts-with selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Looking at other SO questions, I've learnt that `*=` means "contains" and `^=` means "starts with".  I noticed `[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {/* CSS Here */}` in some third-party CSS code.  This strikes me as redundant; I am unclear why `[class*=" icon-"] {/* CSS Here */}` would not have been sufficient.

Does the redundant use of the `^=` selector serve any purpose (e.g., readability, older browser support, etc.)?

Question reference:
[What is caret symbol ^ used for in css when selecting elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130765/what-is-caret-symbol-used-for-in-css-when-selecting-elements)
[What does an asterisk before an equal sign mean (*=) ? What about the exclamation mark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525542/what-does-an-asterisk-before-an-equal-sign-mean-what-about-the-exclamatio)

Comment: Where is that construct used? Looks redundand and should probably be `[class*="icon-"]` (No space, just one selector)

Comment: Harry's answer is correct. A similar explanation is also given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix/8588532#8588532

Comment: @Harry: Learnt and Learned are both correct.  Learned is more common in the U.S.

Comment: @Brian: Oh sorry I didn't know that. Thanks for the comment :) My main intent was to correct the typo in the title and add the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a redundant selector. It is possibly used to select the elements with `icon-` class even if it is second one in the class list like in the below snippet.

`[class^="icon-"]` will only select the elements whose value for class attribute starts with `icon-`.

`[class*=" icon-"]` will select all elements that contain a class with `icon-` in its list of classes. Note how they have specifically used a space before.

> **Quoting CodingWithSpike's comment**
>
> `[class*="icon-"]` without a space would also match undesired classes like `not-icon-1` or `lexicon-name` which is likely why the leading space is included.

In essence the selector group is used to select all elements who have **at least one class which begins with `icon-`** as part of their class list.

```css
[class^="icon-"] {
  color: green;
}
[class*=" icon-"] {
  color: red;
}
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  background: beige;
}

[class*="icon-"]{
  border: 1px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-1">Only Icon class</div>
<div class="a icon-1">Some other class before</div>
<div class="a not-icon-1">Some other class before</div>
```

Comment: `[class*="icon-"]` without a space would also match undesired classes like `not-icon-1` or `lexicon-name` which is likely why the leading space is included.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike: Absolutely spot on. I didn't think of that :)