# CSS3 selector matching value beginning with "[attribute^=value]" is not matching value that has space(s) after quotation

Tags: css, css-selectors

The

```
div[class^="test"]
```

selector will not match an element in markup if the element will be

```
class="  test-something"
```

(The intended selector had been generated on backend.)

The

```
div[class^="  test"]
```

is not an option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Won't `div[class*="test"]` work for your case? That is a contains match so have to be careful with usage. It would even match `class="detest"`. You could probably have a look at a combination of starts-with and contains selectors like mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140304/if-already-using-the-contains-selector-why-use-the-starts-with-selector/31140727#31140727) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix/8588532#8588532).

Comment: Please include your HTML so we know what we're targeting. Otherwise our answers will be just guesses.

Comment: @TylerH
You have markup on the second code example line.

Comment: Are you trying to match `test123`? If not, use `.test` or `[class~=test]`.

Comment: @torazaburo 
what kind of question is this?

Comment: @Blix While there's not even enough markup in the post to reproduce the error, I have to assume that there's more to the class names than you've shared, since your title and post indicate that something should be following "test", but in your partial code, there's nothing. Otherwise, why use the `attr` selector at all? `.test {}` is what you should be using.

Comment: @Blix *What kind of question is this?* I am saying, as have several other commenters, that if you want to match a `div` with the class `test`, all you need to do is to specify `div.test`. What exactly do you want to select?

Comment: @TylerH
You have enough of info. The question was not about how to select element but about using "beginning with" selector in case there is a space between quotation and  class name.

Comment: @torazaburo
At first `div.test` is a bad practice.  That should be `.test` and second I was asking about why the 'begin with' selector is not working on space. Not about how to select the element. Anyway, the answer had been answered.

Comment: @Blix but that's not what the `[attr^=value]` selector is for. You are using the "begins with" selector to select something that is at the end. You should know this won't work because *in your title* you refer to it as the "*begins* with" selector. Also, `div.test` is not bad practice at all. Who told you that?

Comment: @Blix: How is that even relevant here? Fine, forget the others ever mentioned the tagname and just go with `.test` then. Does *that* work for you? If not, why not?

Comment: Also, I agree with @Harry that this is most likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix judging by the situation you've described.

Comment: @Blix the reason `div.test` is bad practice in certain (and not all) cases is because it could be an overqualifying selector, which in that case `div[class^="test"]` would be just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did there `^=` is:

> 'begins with..'

```
div[class^="test"] { }
```

which would work on something like this:

```
<div class="test and-some-class"></div>  
<!-- only if the very first string in your class matches "test" -->
<!-- so, class=" test something-else" won't work
```

**You would have to use the CSS Selector:**

> 'contains..'

```
div[class*="test"] { }
```

which would work on

```
<div class="class test something-else"></div> 
<!-- class name can be anything. "test" can be anywhere -->
```

**Reference**

- [CSS3 Attribute Selectors: Substring Matching](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-attribute-selectors-substring-matching/)

Comment: @torazaburo The first is an example of how to properly use the `[attr^=value]` selector.

Comment: @torazaburo Firstly, I never said that the first one is an answer, is just an example of what he tried and how it is actually working. As for the my "second" that is the actual answer and yes, it will match `abctestdef` as well, but as far as I know, there is no other way of matching a class. Secondly, I guess it is an answer as it does what the OP was asking